# Speeding up vocal messages on instagram

Tags: audio, instagram, instagram-api

I know the question seems strange, but I want to know if it is possible in some maniere to speed up the speed of listening of a vocal message on instagram.

I am currently trying to create an mobile app that could do that, and much more. But this is the principal thing it needs. And i start the creation on the app by doing it on a cumputer to continue improving it.

Currently, I don't have a specific coding language, but it will be an app on mobile.

So, **do you think that with something we could speed up the speed of listening of a vocal message on instagram?**